# Update all data with ef and mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an list of items in my database. I'm using Asp.Net MVC with Entity Framework.

My doubt is:

I have a method that goes to update all items in my database, but with one rule!

I have to select all users in my database then I have to divide all items in my database and  update it with the user code.

I think I have to use a `foreach` in my users and then I have to go updating my items, correct?

Exists an form to update for example 50 items once and then I fire the db.SaveChanges!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the user count, this is probably is a sort of operation you better perform from *outside* the OR/M framework. I don't know EF in the details, so check before if it support out of the box some sort of "bulk operations" otherwise go with a straigth update with a query. Leveraging some so calle micro OR/M can help too.

Comment: there is another way however, you could write a sproc and execute with   the EF because there is no way to guarantee that your system will always be 5 users this will be more scalable.